# Can registered guest stay in other room of the same hotel?

Tags: hotels, south-korea

My girlfriend has just come to Seoul in a group of tourists. I'm already in Seoul since I study there. Because we want to spend a night with each other so I thinking about booking a (double) room for 2 in the same hotel with her room.

And then could she just leave her booked room (with the tourism group) to come and stay with me that night ?

Comment: I am a little puzzled here about what your problem even is. Who would care? The hotel is not shortcharged since you said  you are booking a room for two. The police? Well, your GF could leave a note in her room in the extremely unlikely case the authorities come and look for her but that just doesn't happen (unless she is a Jamie Bond or some such). So... why do you think this could be a problem?

Comment: Oh. This is my first time in this kind of situation. Sometime they have some silly rule so I just want to make sure before book the room.

Comment: @chx: In most places, as long as there is no curfew in place for some reason, there is no obligation to be in one's booked hotel room at any given time. (If anything, hotels may be opposed to someone being in a hotel room they're not supposed to be in, but among paying guests at a comparable rate, they really shouldn't normally care.)

Comment: And if your girlfriend isn't sharing a room with somebody from her tour group, consider contacting the hotel beforehand and simply upgrade her single to a double. (Odds are the single is already a double anyway and your only surcharges will be for breakfast and local taxes...)

Comment: What age is your girlfriend?

Comment: Lol, we're both far older than 18 yo Sherlock

Comment: Following up on O.R.Mapper's comment: the only concern I'd have would be between your girlfriend and her tour group. They at least should be advised, as they may have liability or responsibility processes that depend on knowing where their tour members are spending the night. Like they may need to be able to contact them, or the group may have a buddy system for emergencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem at all in South Korea. You can come an go at your leisure and unless you are blatantly violating a hotel policy or local law, no one will care. Rules  may be slightly different for minors but that's more up to the chaperones or parents, then the hotels

In fact, for most "normal" bookings, you could stay in the room of your girlfriend without having to buy an extra room. Some hotels may charge you a little extra depending on the time of reservation but most bookings include 2 people, even if you book as a single person.